# Django url with more parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I have these two Django url definitions:

1 - First Url

```
url( r'^(?P<language>.*)/(?P<shop>.*)/(?P<brand>.*)/$', 'app.views.view_1' ),
```

E.g.: http://www.example.com/en/my-shop/my-brand/

2 - Second Url

```
url( r'^(?P<language>.*)/(?P<shop>.*)/(?P<brand>.*)/(?P<category>.*)/$', 'app.views.view_2' ),
```

E.g.: http://www.example.com/en/my-shop/my-brand/my-brand-category/

**Issue:** When I call the FIRST url, django url dispatcher correctly calls the "app.views.view_1" view. But, when I call the SECOND url, the url dispatcher calls AGAIN the "app.views.view_1" view instead to call the "app.views.view_2" view.

What is the problem? Wrong Regex?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capturing groups match any characters, including the slash. You could fix this by putting the more specific one first, but it's better in any case to constrain them a bit: a common format for slugs is alphanumeric characters plus dash. Also, you probably want to use + rather than *, as you will need at least one character for each group.

```
r'^(?P<language>[\w-]+)/(?P<shop>[\w-]+)/(?P<brand>[\w-]+)/$'
```

and the same for the other pattern.

Comment: Many thanks! I will try your solution this night at home and I will give you a response. Thanks!